# Is there any way to bring an application window to foreground in electron by its window id

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to bring an application window to foreground from the data which I get from desktopCapturer.getSources(),

```
    desktopCapturer.getSources({
                        types: ['window', 'screen'],
                    })
                    .then(async sources => {
                        console.log(sources)
}
```

I want to know if there is any possible way to bring the application to front/foreground from the data (which we get from sources)

Comment: typically people do not share the image of code in question, they directly copy and paste the code.

Comment: @Sukumaar the above image is of the console( console.log(sources) )

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893426/bringing-an-electron-app-to-foreground-with-a-global-shortcut-like-spotlight-la

Comment: @Rajesh this could only bring the electron application window to front, I want to bring other application windows (such as VScode or finder, terminal window) to front.